# Google Consent Mode V2 In the Android Studio logcat, can not find the log message "ad_personalization=denied" or "ad_personalization=granted"

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, logcat, admob-cookieconsent

Google Consent Mode V2
In the Android Studio logcat,
can not find the log message "ad_personalization=denied" or "ad_personalization=granted"

but can find:
Setting consent, ... analytics_storage=granted
Setting consent, ... ad_storage=granted`your text`
Setting consent, ... ad_user_data=granted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OAPt.png)
I just upgraded to consent mode v2 based on this document:
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/app-consent?platform=android

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have the same problem, ad_personalization is not showing on logcat and i followed the instructions on documentation https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/security/guides/app-consent?platform=android and i have a warning on google analytics because it can not detect signals of ad_personalization